# Text width not as specified in memoir

Tags: formatting, memoir

How come I cannot get the specified text width? Here's the MWE that demonstrates my problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setstocksize{29.7cm}{21.0cm} % A4 stock
\settrimmedsize{29.7cm}{21.0cm}{*}
\setlength{\trimtop}{0.0cm}
\setlength{\trimedge}{0.0cm}
\settypeblocksize{15cm}{12cm}{*}
\setlrmargins{2.0cm}{*}{*}
\setulmargins{2.0cm}{*}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}
```

This does not produce a text block of height 15 cm by width 12 cm, but only 13.8 cm by 11 cm. Furthermore, the spine margin is not 2 cm, but 2.6 cm. I'm not concerned about the difference in text height, only about the width. Oddly, the output of \checkandfixthelayout does not correspond to what I actually see on the page (so I assume nothing was fixed). Instead, it corresponds to what I specified:

```
Top and edge trims: 0pt and 0pt
Text height and width: 430pt by 341pt (15.11 cm by 11.98 cm)
Spine and edge margins: 56.9055pt and 199.16931pt (20.00 cm)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The text height is adjusted so that an integer number of lines fit; 341pt is 11.985mm, so it's what's expected. Also 56.9055pt is almost exactly 2cm (the difference is a few scaled points).

Comment: See also the optional arguments that may be given to `\checkandfixthelayout`.  You can use `fixed`, `classic` (default), `lines`, and `nearest`.

Comment: @egreg: Of course, you're right about the text height being dependent on the number of lines, which is why I'm not worried about the small difference. My main concern is the width.

Comment: @jon: Thanks for the pointer, but for the moment I'm not concerned about the height, only the width. I will clarify my question.

Comment: I get 12cm width with your code. How are you measuring the width? If you are printing it and using a ruler, make sure you tell your PDF viewer/printer not to "fit", "shrink" or "scale".

Comment: @Dan Adobe Reader has the peculiar habit of not believing that A4 paper fits in A4 paper and reduces it.

Comment: @Dan & egreg: That turned out to be the problem, sorry for wasting everybody's time. I don't know why this happens, though, since I'm creating the document with a4paper as the option, so why would Reader think it needs to be scaled?

Comment: @user1362373 There are several possible values a PDF file may contain that denote the "size" of a page: `MediaBox`, `CropBox`, `TrimBox`, etc. Only `MediaBox` is required, `CropBox` defaults to `MediaBox`, and the rest default to `CropBox`. I *think* Reader decides to shrink if the smallest of these is larger than the printable area of the paper. The actual extent of ink on a page in TeX is hard to determine, so usually only `MediaBox` is set in PDF files output by pdftex, and its size is `\pdfpagewidth` by `\pdfpageheight`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about scaling done by Adobe Reader during printing.